# Max-height of table row using pure HTML + CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, size

I have a table containing orders. Some cells contain icons, some contains text, and one contains a table. The last cell contains a long text, which is displayed within a `<div>` with `overflow:auto`.

I would like to set the `max-height` of this `<div class="textDiv">` to be equal to the highest cell in the row. Currently I do it with jQuery:

- I render the table with the `<div class="textDiv" style="display:none;">`
- then I use jQuery after the content is loaded:

  ```
  $('.textDiv').each(function (i, obj) {
      $(obj).css('max-height', $(obj).parent().height() + 'px').css('display', 'block');
  });
  ```

Is there a pure HTML + CSS way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByCalssName("textDiv");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    divs[i].style.maxHeight = divs[i].parentElement.style.height;
    // or window.getComputedStyle(divs[i].parentElement, null).height;
    divs[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: I guess you have misunderstood me, I'm looking for a pure HTML+CSS solution, without any form of JS.